# Sqlconnection does not support parallel transactions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to run two transactions simultaneously. So i gave MultipleActiveResultSet = false in the connection string as specified in an MSDN article. But after modifying the connection string i get "Target machine actively refused". I'm working with WCF.

Any ideas in this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was under the impression that MARS only really applies to the special case of getting multiple forward-only read-only resultsets on a single connection, but that regular operations have to have their own connections.

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain what you're trying to do please?

A transaction is atomic and isolated (so effectively per connection). You can't do 2 simultaneous transactions for one connection/session: it makes no sense

Comment: An MSDN page for SQL Server Compact mentions "does support parallel transactions in ADO .NET" http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172400(SQL.90).aspx, though I'm unsure what it means

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure "Target machine actively refused" is related to parallel transactions?

It usuall means the machine is not listening on the port you're trying to talk to.

Comment: Yes. If i remove the MultipleActiveResultSet entry from the connection string, everything works fine.

Comment: Can you post the connection string (without password ofc)?

Comment: Okie, i now feel that my question is absurd. The problem is with the code logic. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I did this mistake:

```
SqlConnection Con=new SqlConnection(_myConString);
SqlTransaction tr=Con.CreateTransaction();
tr=Con.CreateTransaction();
```

Line 2 and 3 are creating transactions. Hence I was receiving the error. I rectified, and problem got solved.

Conclusion: Calling CreateTransaction before Completing the running transaction causes the above exception.